# Send email from the localhost 7143

Tags: php, email

I am working on localhost 7143 and I want to send an email from my webpage and I need to work on this port.

I have PHPMailer working on 127.0.0.1 and sending an email but can I somehow use what I have working there to send an email from localhost 7143

Comment: The mail server does not occupy the same port as the web server. Leave the port alone for that unless you've changed the port for your mail server as well.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. As the other comments mentions, the port that the webserver is listening on is unrelated to the port that the SMTP server might be listening on. Just write your code, using the SMTP server settings (host, port, auth) you know about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys I am new to programming so i am not 100% sure what I am talking about.What I am trying to say is working with most tutorials online they work from localhost 127.0.0.1 and i got that working but as my project is on localhost 7143 i need to send email from there and  i have the email form put in there but when i try send I just get a not found on the top left corner.I have xampp working with the email service

Comment: What url is your email form posting to?.

Comment: http://localhost:7143/ is what i have initially and when i press send this comes up http://localhost:7143/opt/lammp/htdocs/sendmail.php it tries to read the sendmail.php file i suppose.Not found also appears on top corner.This works on localhost but not on localhost:7143